# elasticsearch phraze term frequency .tf() containing multiple words

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I want to access frequency of a phraze combined from multiple words
e.g. "green energy"

I can access tf of "green" and "energy", example:

```
"function_score":
{
    "filter" : {
        "terms" : { "content" : ["energy","green"]}
    },
    "script_score": {
        "script": "_index['content']['energy'].tf() + _index['content']['green'].tf()",
        "lang":"groovy"
    }
}
```

This works fine. However, how can I find the frequency of a term "green energy" as

```
_index['content']['green energy'].tf()
```

does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on how you have your data indexed and what requirements you have when searching. For example, if you have "indirect green energy to spare" (meaning, "green" and "energy" are close one to each other) and you want your script to "match" for "green energy" and give you a tf() evaluation then you need to index your data accordingly. Just like you said - "frequency of a term 'green energy'" boils down to producing somehow that term "green energy".

One idea in your case is to use another field for `"content"` but with `"shingles"` analyzer:

```
PUT /some_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "my_shingle_filter": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 2,
          "output_unigrams": false
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "my_shingle_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "my_shingle_filter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "some_type": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed",
          "fields": {
            "with_shingles": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in your function score, you would reference that `.with_shingles` field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "content": [
            "energy",
            "green"
          ]
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        "script": "_index['content.with_shingles']['green energy'].tf()",
        "lang": "groovy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is just an example to prove that you need to index your data accordingly so that you can get that `.tf()` you want. In my example, I assumed you want to search for the exact term "green energy" so I used "shingles" that, for the text as an example above, results in an analyzed list of terms like this: `"content.with_shingles": ["energy to","green energy","indirect green","to spare"]`.

Comment: Perfect, many thanks. Just a note for other guys: do not forget to URL encode your your json request. 'green energy' should become 'green+energy'